# Getting the document-per-topic loading using TextmineR package by passing term co-occurrence matrix

Tags: r, text-mining, word-embedding

I am using [TextmineR](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/textmineR/vignettes/d_text_embeddings.html) package to find the most similar documents to given document list. I used the following code to generate the ***tcm*** not ***dtm***

```
tcm <- CreateTcm(doc_vec = text_df$Description,
                 skipgram_window = 20,
                 verbose = FALSE,
                 cpus = 2)
```

Which is used to fit a lda model:

```
# note the number of topics is arbitrary here
# see extensions for more info


model <- FitLdaModel(dtm = tcm, 
                     k = 25,
                     iterations = 200, # I usually recommend at least 500 iterations or more
                     burnin = 180,
                     alpha = 0.1,
                     beta = 0.05,
                     optimize_alpha = TRUE,
                     calc_likelihood = TRUE,
                     calc_coherence = TRUE,
                     calc_r2 = TRUE,
                     cpus = 2)
```

Now the model parameter ***theta*** here generates word-per-topic loading rather than document-per-topic loading. I want to retrieve  the document number from the document-per-topic loading. Please help in suggesting the method to obtain the document-per-topic distribution from this model while passing term co-occurrence matrix.

I have tried to back connect to get document number from document-per-topic loading, but not successful as per the guidelines given at  https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/textmineR/vignettes/d_text_embeddings.html

Answer (score 1):

11-month old question. But giving it a shot anyway.

Technically, `theta` with LDA embeddings gives you P(topic|word) and `phi` still gives you P(word|topic). If I understand you correctly, you want to embed whole documents under this model? If so, here's how you'd do it.

```
library(textmineR)

# create a tcm
tcm <- CreateTcm(nih_sample$ABSTRACT_TEXT, skipgram_window = 10)

# fit an LDA model
m <- FitLdaModel(dtm = tcm, k = 100, iterations = 100, burnin = 75)

# pull your documents into a dtm
d <- nih_sample_dtm

# get them predicted under the model
# I recommend using the "dot" method for prediction with embeddings as sparsity may
# result in underflow and throw an error using the default "gibbs" method
p <- predict(object = m, newdata = d, method = "dot")
```